# issues in setting item level permissions in itemupdated - modified by -system account - check in enabled

Tags: event-receivers, itemupdated

i am using the below  code to set  permissions for different folders within a  document library in my sp 2013 publishing site collection.
 the issue i am facing, is   for a  particular folder  , say "knowledge documents" , whatever be the documents uploaded  by the end users, i want to implement the  item level permissions.
so i wrote the below code in the itemupdated event handler
also **am having versioning enabled and check- in and check out also enabled**
so when I try apply the permissions, am getting the permissions, but the modified by was changed to system account,.

How to resolve this situation?, if i write the file.checkout forcibly and call the method , and then **item.update()** again its failing to update the **modified by** .

```
       public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);

          SPUser currUser = properties.Web.CurrentUser;

           this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
           try
           {
             SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                   {

                    SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId);
                    SPWeb CurrentWeb = 
                    CurrentSite.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl);
                    SPList CurrentList = CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];
                    SPListItem CurrentListItem;
                    SPWeb myRootWeb = CurrentSite.RootWeb;
                    CurrentListItem = CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId].GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID);  //properties.ListItem; commented prasad on 25th aprl

                    SPFile spfile = CurrentListItem.Web.GetFile(CurrentListItem.Url);
                    SPFolder spfileFolder = spfile.ParentFolder;

                    if (CurrentListItem != null)// && isFolder== true)
                    {
                        CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        if (!CurrentListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                        {
                            CurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                            CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        }



                        SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments;
                        for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignmentSingle = SPRoleAssColn[i];
                            System.Type t = roleAssignmentSingle.Member.GetType();
                            if (t.Name == "SPGroup" || t.Name == "SPUser")
                                SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                      if (spfileFolder.Name.Equals("Knowledge Documents"))
                    {
                        SPUser spevery1nodelete = CurrentWeb.EnsureUser("Everyone");
                        SPRoleDefinition mroleDefinitionevery1nodelete = CurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions["ContributeNoDelete"];
                        SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignmentevery1nodelete = new SPRoleAssignment(spevery1nodelete);
                        spRoleAssignmentevery1nodelete.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(mroleDefinitionevery1nodelete);
                        CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(spRoleAssignmentevery1nodelete);

                        SPUser spUsrEnsuredUser = CurrentWeb.EnsureUser(currUser.LoginName);
                        SPRoleAssignment mroleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spUsrEnsuredUser);
                        SPRoleDefinition mroleDefinition = CurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
                        mroleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(mroleDefinition);
                        CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(mroleAssignment);

                        //this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

                        if (CurrentListItem.File.CheckOutType.ToString() == "None")
                        {
                            CurrentListItem.File.CheckOut();
                            CurrentListItem.Update();
                            CurrentListItem.File.CheckIn("Programmatically Checked In");
                            CurrentListItem["Editor"] = currUser.ID;

                        }

                    }
```

[image: modified-by-system-account]

Comment: Can you elaborate ? What is the issue here ?

Comment: Please, explain the question. What is the issue ?

Comment: sorry, i was in the middle of something, so could not explain. i wil update the question now.

Comment: I have updated my question and my issue  with screen shot. I am forcefully check-in the document.Also am check-out before calling .update() method.so,  wanted to check, how can i remove the "system account " using code and replace with the **Editor** .